# Windows 11 Power Settings - Monitor will not turn off / sleep if set to more than 5 minutes

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11, power-management

I've been trying to resolve this issue for several months. It was present in Windows 10 prior to upgrading as well. I'm currently on Windows 11 22H2.

Under Settings > System > Power > Screen and sleep if I change the setting for
`When plugged in, turn off my screen after` and set it to 10 minutes or more, the display never turns off. However, as soon as I change the setting to 5 minutes or less, it always works.

My screensaver is completely disabled and I have tried running the Windows Troublehsooter for Power to check and fix the power setting. However, the Power Troubleshooter always changes those settings back to 5 minutes and then sets `When plugged in, put my device to sleep after` to 15 minutes. I don't want my device to sleep as I often connect to my system from remote locations, but I do want the monitors to power off/sleep after 10 or 15 minutes.

Anyone have any ideas?

Other than Windows Troubleshooter, I have also tried sfc /scannow and the DISM tool and it has had no effect.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like they never fixed this issue in Windows 11. I'd resort to alternative methods. Such as using a Scheduled Task and a batch file with nircmd to turn off your monitor, and another one to turn it back on.

Comment: @LPChip Is this a known issue / bug? Anywhere that I can read up on it?

Comment: My only research is that when I faced it, I read that many others also had it, and that they used other means to bypass it. So that's what I did myself.

Comment: @spaceman-spiff Does your screen stay off permanently with the setting of 5 minutes or does it turn on after about 10 minutes, as if there is an interrupt by e.g. an USB device? What happens if you set 6,7,8,9,10 minutes via advanced power options (command as shortcut: `PowerCfg.cpl @0,/editplan:`)?

Comment: @swbbl if set to 5 minutes, once the monitors turn off they stay off until I move the mouse or keyboard.  Will test with incrementing in 1 minute intervals and will report back

Comment: Further testing and anything beyond 5m and it won't ever sleep, but if I set to 5m it always sleeps the screen / monitor and stays off until I wake it with mouse or keyboard.  So very strange!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the monitor timeout using `powercfg.exe` from an elevated command prompt might resolve inconsistent behaviour where windows doesn't recognize the change being made in `ms-settings:powersleep` or `PowerCfg.cpl @0,/editplan:`.

```
C:\Windows\System32\powercfg.exe -change -monitor-timeout-ac 6
```

Afterwards, the system may again begin to honor changes made via either of the common GUI options.

**Explanation**:
I cannot entirely explain why the above solution may work, but it resolved the issue on my system and the fix has persisted through multiple reboots and regardless of the method to change the timeout (i.e.Settings, Control Panel applet or command prompt). After running the above command to change `Turn off display after` time to 6 minutes, the system began to honor all times beyond 5 minutes.

This *should* be the same as changing the setting in the `PowerCfg.cpl @0,/editplan:` However, in this case it seems to have totally resolved the issue.  It's possible there was a hidden permissions issue and using an elevated command prompt was able to force a hidden permissions change.

Comment: This problem resurfaced and has now been confirmed as a bug from the 3rd party software program CompanionLink when it's Realtime sync is enabled.  I still can't explain why the elevated command prompt resolved the behavior the first time, but it resurfaced 4 weeks ago. Likely as the result of a recent update to Companionlink.  They have acknowledged the bug and are working on a fix.